# kubectl exec fails "cannot validate certificate because it doesn't contain any IP SANs"

Tags: ssl, kubernetes

I'm trying to use kubectl exec to enter one of my containers, but I'm getting stuck on this error.

```
$ kubectl exec -it ubuntu -- bash
error: Unable to upgrade connection: {
    "kind": "Status",
    "apiVersion": "v1",
    "metadata": {},
    "status": "Failure",
    "message": "x509: cannot validate certificate for <worker_node_ip> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs",
    "code": 500
}
```

I have configured kubectl with my CA certificate and admin keys, etc according to this guide https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/1.0.6/configure-kubectl.html

### Update

I also found the same error in the API server's logs

```
E1125 17:33:16.308389 1 errors.go:62] apiserver received an error that is not an unversioned.Status: x509: cannot validate certificate for <worker_node_ip> because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
```

Does this mean I have configured the certs incorrectly on my worker/master nodes or on kubectl on my local machine?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you used this command to create your certificate:

```
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem \
    -CAcreateserial -out server-cert.pem
```

Then your issue can be resolved by doing the following as the 'client' cert uses an -extfile extfile.cnf:

```
echo subjectAltName = IP:worker_node_ip > extfile.cnf
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -CA ca.pem -CAkey ca-key.pem -CAcreateserial \
   -out server-cert.pem -extfile extfile.cnf
```

You can specify any number of IP addresses, such as IP:127.0.0.1,IP:127.0.1.1 (non localhost as well).

Comment: As George said, you need the IPs of your kubelet hosts in the cert. This is a known issue with the current CoreOS documentation/certificate build process. See https://github.com/coreos/coreos-kubernetes/issues/73 for more detail.

Comment: So looking at the coreos guide, do I need to add this config to when I create the apiserver key or the worker key?

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Kubernetes with a Google Container Cluster, this may fix the issue as it did for me:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials <cluster-name> \
    --project <project-name> --zone <zone>
```

Answer (score 1):

That message is coming from the master trying to connect to the node (the flow of traffic is `kubectl -> master API -> kubelet -> container`). When starting the master, are you setting `--kubelet_certificate_authority`? If so, the master expects to be able to validate the kubelet's serving cert, which means it needs to be valid for the hostnames/IP addresses the master uses to connect to it.

Comment: Im not using that option. My cert-related options are `--tls-cert-file` `--tls-private-key-file` `--client-ca-file` and `--service-account-key-file`. Does kubelet need the master API's public key, or vice versa?